# Why can't I use Quick Replace in Visual Studio while building a solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013 to work on a solution containing a bunch of C++ projects. In my daily workflow, I often change the code of one project and rebuild it (which can take a significant amount of time), and at the same time I continue to work on another project within the same solution.

I noticed that the `Quick Replace` functionality (as found in `Edit > Find and Replace > Quick Replace (CTRL + H)`) is not available for any project as long as building is not completed or interrupted. In particular, the field "Search term" is always available (and thus I can continue to search whatever I want), but the corresponding "Replacement term" is grayed out.

Why does Visual Studio inhibit Search&Replace while building the solution? Is there an possibility to avoid this behavior?

Comment: It's probably a safety mechanism to prevent  a race condition where the user starts a build, the file is modified, and the build gets to the modified file.  I think most users expect build to work atomically.  Since the quick replace dialog can span projects, it was probably easier to disable it completely during a build than to make sure it was safe in every situation.  Microsoft could probably improve the functionality, but I doubt it is very high on their priority list.

Comment: At first, I also thought it might be a kind of safety mechanism. But at the same time I can easily edit and save any source file while the build is running (yes, including files belonging to the currently build project). If your argumentation was true, these user interactions are much more likely, can cause the same trouble for the build process and hence Microsoft should block these as well.

Comment: They may be using different mechanisms to save the changes.  I believe Find / Replace allows you to make changes to files that are not actually open in the editor.  The editor probably has additional safeguards build in to make sure that modified files do not interfere with the build (Shadow Copy maybe?).  It may also just be an oversight that was never fixed.  Either way, I don't think can be answered other than by the Microsoft employee responsible for the feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works for me: I can load the same solution in a second session of Visual Studio and build the modified project (or the entire solution) over there.
In the meantime I can continue to use the first session of Visual Studio to work on other projects within the same solution. This way the `quick replace` functionality remains useable all the time.

Not exactly what I was hoping for, but it's nonetheless a workaround that suits me well.